# Access is denied while moving a file from different volumes

Tags: windows-7, administrator

i have a portable 500GB HDD plugged into my dell xps system. The system have windows 7 professional edition. the problem is that when i try to open a file(visual studio .sln file) it is saying that **access is denied**. I cannot copy this file to a different location(within my local HDD) it is saying that i **need permission for the task to complete**.

I've checked and confirmed the following things

1) I've logged into an admin account before attempting these operations
2) My admin account have 'Full Control'
3) I've full control over the portable HDD
4) I changed the 'UAC' settings to 'Never notify'

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, this has nothing to do with UAC.

It has to do with File permissions.

Where does your admin account have "Full Control"?  Of the sln file?

Under your portable harddrive, make sure "User" group or your account has write and modify permissions.  You can do so by right-clicking the file and then going to the Security tab.

Check to make sure the Users group has write permissions.  Moving a file will involve deleting it, so this is why you need write permissions.